# Adding Neo4j DB drivers to NetBeans 8.2

Tags: java, jdbc, neo4j, netbeans-8

downloaded neo4j-jdbc-driver-3.0.jar and installed the bolt, jdbc and http drivers in NetBeans 8.2

Trying to connect NB to the (running) neo4j database. Get cannot find driver error: Cannot establish a connection to bolt://localhost:7687 using org.neo4j.jdbc.bolt.BoltDriver (Unable to find a suitable driver)

What did I miss?

Thanks

Comment: Did you add these drivers to your CLASSPATH & the project's BUILDPATH?

Comment: Did add to the project's CLASSPATH ... but this is in reference to using the "services" tab to start a connection to the Neo4j default.graphdb ... hoping this makes available the nodes, relationships and properties to the projects

Comment: Using this URI,jdbc:neo4j:bolt://localhost, a successful connection was reported using either the jdbc driver or the bolt driver.  However, neither found a schema.  Trying the URI with the "base driver" and "http" driver did not result in a successful connection.  The database server is running and the test java code with hard coded connection does work as expected.